# How to start working independently in a project?

Tags: professionalism, communication, ethics

It has been two months since I joined in this new project. I have put to work along with another postdoc researcher. Now we both have been asked to set a pipeline for sequencing analysis. This person whom I have to work is like 20 yrs older than me and have gained some experience in the field. I respect his knowledge and experience. But, he gets tensed and sometimes doesn't talk or let me know on what he is working. He lets me know latter about things he has been doing. It also gets stressfull when I have to tell each step of my work. He keeps checking every detail and lot of time goes wasted. He is sometimes very slow. I like to be professional and also work in peace. I also like to get his advice and suggestions in some of the steps. How do I set boundaries without touching his ego, so that project work doesn't become affected? I am thinking to have digital lab book where I can update what I have been working on. So he can know the steps that I have been working on. Please someone advice

Comment: what you're describing isn't a team, it's you working for them.  you need the person who directs both of you to get involved.

Comment: @Tiger Guy We both report about the current status of the project to the lab head. We both work together to set the lab pipeline. Lab head doesn't have any background on the computational work,so very unlikely to be involved. But there is another person associated with this lab for many years and he works remotely. He gives some inputs on this kind of computational work and he seem to be interested in helping with pipeline.  The person (with whom I have problem ) shares less information with this person working remotely.

Comment: What level are you, there is a very big difference in expectations for a masters student verse another postdoc.